# How to implement cheat proof trading system in a game?

Tags: anti-cheat

I want to make a game where you can trade items you find from the world, the world would be static, so the master server would always know exactly how much items of X there are etc.

What should i take into account when building such a system?

I want to avoid people being able to cheat and filling the game with free items, but at the same time i want it to be as less server dependant as possible, as i cant afford buying thousands of servers just to run their games on them constantly, even if i had the money, i would prefer not make people to rely on my servers so they can be playing it at any time they want at anywhere, but if they want to ensure the validity of the objects he is going to buy from someone, he would have to connect to the master server if he wants to ensure the objects validity.

But how could i know which objects are genuine and which are fake? So i thought i would give each object in the world an unique ID which cannot be guessed. But then again, wouldnt i have to somehow prove that i collected those items with valid actions? And how could i possibly do that without making the server to run my game from the beginning? And how could i prevent someone trading the same item twice etc.

So i thought i could use a Bitcoin system, but i dont know much about it and im not sure would this be an option since there would be a lot of trading, and a lot more "coins" to trade, so the amount of history information might be too much to handle, not to mention i want to prevent people from cheating in any way, for example you cant trade stuff from the other side of the world and magically teleport the items there (assuming you dont own a teleport atm), you would have to move the items across the world, which would take some time. Also im not very excited about the fact that Bitcoins generation will use intense amounts of CPU power, and im not sure would there be enough Bitcoins for everyone to use; everyone should have equal chance of getting items without depending how fast CPU they have, and im not sure how it would work with fractions of items (like 0.1 of money etc).

Any thoughts and ideas appreciated.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that each player essentially has a separate copy of the game world which runs locally on their system, but you want to allow players to trade items between worlds?

Comment: yes, although i wouldnt allow players having the whole world, only those areas they have explored. also, two players cant have the same location in the world, so they cant overlap. once you are done playing and you go offline, you upload your stuff to server so others can see where you are spread at the moment to prevent overlapping and to allow players seeing each other worlds.

Comment: @ilmari, oh and the players could see the whole world, but wont see where all the items are until they explore.

Answer (score 9):

The basic idea is trust. Who can you trust? Nobody. So, don't. Don't let the users decide anything, everything that requires trust happens on the server.

Items only "exist" on the server. Money only "exists" on the server. The clients can do requests (like "I'd like to sell item X"), the server sees who owns what, and thus you can't sell something you don't own. Or buy stuff with money that the server knows you have.

Only delegate things to clients that don't really matter, like particle systems, motion prediction, that sort of stuff.

(Of course you may end up having to trust the client in some things for performance / gameplay reasons, but know that it's always a risk).

Comment: it could be as simple as that; items just are on the server and just check if player X has item Y etc. but, the real problem is how to make it sure player X doesnt steal all the items from the world by simply telling the server "i have item X now" million times for all of the items there. so the server would need to know the player got the item legitimately. this is where i need some ideas!

Comment: Why would you trust the client to say he has some item? the server can is the only authority that can tell whether the player has the item or not. Don't trust the client!

Comment: So let's say client says "pick up object X", the server has to check whether that's possible or not, and make decision based on the facts that it has.

Comment: yes, thats the problem... only way to do that is to run the games on those servers! and i cant afford that. its not as simple as "pick up item x if its in range y", the rules are way more complex than that (and will get more complicated in time). which why i would need to run the games on the server, right? but i want to avoid that.

Comment: Then you basically can't do it in a secure manner. When you give the control to the user, you're basically saying "here's a box of goodies, but it's locked; only open it with this key which I also happen to provide to you".

Comment: There are ways to make it *harder*, but it's always a losing battle. See DRM.

Comment: thats why i was thinking of bitcoins, thats pretty secure system. but i guess you are right... but anyways, i still need suggestions to reduce the cheatability: i was thinking of "trusted users" like moderators on the forums etc. or what about tracking who made the items, and if someone cheated those items, we could just delete them from every player and thus removing the problem...

Comment: If you put those "coins" in the game, someone will write a program that will let the player pick up your "coins", regardless of whether they should be accessible or not.

Answer (score 3):

Client A invites Client B to trade through the server (so if A is annoying, B can blacklist him).

If A and B decide to trade item N and M, they both sent an 'OK for N and M) to the server.

Server makes the change and sends messages to A and B.

**No P2P, No bitcoins, No 'trust the client just a bit'.**

Simple, fast secure and easy (you can even log the transactions!). What do the world need more than that?

Oh yes, "...I cant afford buying thousands of servers...".

I have a server up and running, the game isn't 100% about trading but you can do it and the bandwith it uses is about nothing.
I pay somewhere about 25 dollars or 18 euros a month for the server + a 100Mbit connection.
There can be quite a lot of players trading things there before I need an upgrade.

**In this case I'd say:** Do the game, rent a server (don't buy it) and think about scalability later.

Comment: Even better, use Google App Engine for the trade server so you have a cheap way to handle transactions.

Comment: as i noted in other comments: the real problem is *how* the player gets the items; how do i ensure the player got his stuff from the world legitimately? - Chiguireitor, good idea by using others free(?) servers, didnt think of that!

Comment: Gerry: You can ensure the player got the items legitimately because the server knows where the players are and where the items are, allowing it to say "no" if a player attempts to illegitimately pick an item up.

Comment: its not as simple as "pick up item if player x is in radius of y", i simplified the question a lot to get some general ideas about the topic. the rules behind "picking up items" are way more complicated and thats why i thought "i need thousands of servers"

Comment: Normally the server handles ALL important things, like items. The server will tell player A and B what kind of item they have, the players (clients) themselves will Never send messages like 'I have item 23', 'I have 1000 HP and a does 10000 damage to you', neither to the server nor to another client.
Clients Ask (the server), the Server tells what happened (you tried to change an item you don"t have, You attack with attack Nr 5 you did 15 damage, ...)

Comment: Maybe you can model your trading system like eBay, where the server just handles the publication and ubication, and then you have another server which handles the actual exchange of goods.

Comment: @Chiguireitor, mind elaborate more? im not sure what you are referring at. (i havent used ebay).

Comment: Gerry: Regardless of whether the rules for "picking up items" are simple or complex, the *only* cheat-proof way to enforce them is to only allow clients to tell the server "player X wants to pick up Y", then have the server evaluate the state of the world to determine whether X can legitimately pick up Y and tell the client whether it's allowed or not. If the client is allowed to make that determination, then cheating *will* be possible.

Comment: It's pretty simple: You should have a database with all the published items "for trade" (could be bundles of items too), their respective locations and expected "trade value" (where the trade value is something you must calculate or maybe let the user specify it). Then, you can let the users browse the nearest offers and what they are expecting to receive back for the exchange, then the users could "bid" with an offer and if both parties accept the unchanged trade, the trade is committed and everyone obtains what they accepted. Diablo 2 works this way (also i think Lineage II too).

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, you can't have a totally secure system without an authoritative server.  The best you could do would be some sort of voting system, where clients ask each other if a move is reasonable, and go with a majority vote.  That's basically how the bitcoin system you were talking about works, the theory being that a few cheats are going to get overruled by a mass of legit users.

If you want the player to be able to play offline then upload a game state (that sounds like what you're talking about) then it all gets a whole lot harder.  The best you can do is close your source, encrypt everything, and hope no-one with decent programming skills cares enough to cheat - which is probably a reasonably safe bet.

As with a lot of these sort of problems for indie games (piracy is another example), if you have to care then you're probably successful already.

Comment: yeah but asking everyone if your move is legit or not, may be too much to handle... i mean if i move some guy, i would have to prove it to the main server my move was legit (without making the main server compute it), and how would i do that: i send my whole world to 10 other players, and if majority says its legit then the server would believe me. but theres this little problem i dont want nor i can check for every movement like that.. so the game would then be limited to, lets say 10 users who would basically compute each others movements at all times. eh. how does World Of Warcraft do this?

Comment: im not sure how the encryption would work either... what exactly am i encrypting? would i generate some sort of hash from all the movements, and this hash could be proven valid somehow. but i have no idea how these things work... if you know more about this i would be glad to hear.

Comment: Gerry: WoW does it by having all meaningful events processed solely on the server, which then tells the client the result. The clients do draw results of things like movement in advance, but will snap you back to the "real" position if the server disagrees with the outcome (commonly known as "rubber-banding"). You may have also noticed that, when an MMO lags, you may have to click on an object repeatedly to pick it up, or just click once and then wait several seconds before it pops into your inventory; this is because the client is waiting for the server to OK the action.

Comment: Pretty much the only things that an MMO client will do on its own without the server's intervention are inconsequential, purely cosmetic details, such as particle effects, which don't need to be consistent from one user to the next.

Comment: @dave, maybe that is the only way... i could make it cost money to play monthly like WoW does, just to pay the servers costs, and allow people still play outside of the main servers without any trust.