# Secure login for a game that is open source

Tags: networking, open-source, security

I am making a game which i will be open sourcing. Its a simple arcade like game but requires a network connection because it is meant to be played with other people.

The thing i am worrying about is how would i be sure that the client is the one that i put out for the end user to play with? Kind of a like of sv_pure for Team Fortress 2.

I was thinking of different ways to combat this such as the server requesting the client's version or even it's md5 hash but people with simple java knowledge could just force a method to always return what the server wants.

Comment: -1. Google "secure login". This question shows no research effort, _which is really only in your own interests_. gamedev helps those who help themselves.

Comment: If it's going to be open source, then it's going to be hard to really secure the login.  An md5 hash of the version is a nice simple solution, though.

Comment: An MD5 hash solves nothing - anyone with the code can just edit it to send whatever value they like, removing the hash function entirely.

Comment: related: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/17840/how-to-implement-cheat-proof-trading-system-in-a-game/17842

Comment: I don't get it... You send the client software to the client... He sends you the passward, then you hash it and compare it to the username's password... How can he know the real password?

Comment: The client software is also open source. So you must also know the class that handles the handshake could just as easily be changed so it only sends the hash. But this question was badly asked so i kinda got into 2 different kinds of security problems.

Comment: You could sign all your 'official' JAR files - at runtime merely check that your signature matches (as the JRE will do the actual signature verification for you) - you control the private key for the signing, so you can decide what is official. You could also look into draconian DRM for inspiration (where your 'permanent connection' is with your peer).

Comment: @thedaian you could not be more wrong. Being open source is completely irrelevant to the login system you use, since security by obscurity is wrong anyway.

Comment: @JonathanDickinson is there anyway you can expand on that into an answer?

Comment: @Pureferret sorry, no. I don't have any API-level knowledge of Java: all I know is the basic background of how JAR files are signed. It's also not an appropriate answer for this question. I am sure you will have success if you ask a question such as "How to extract a signature from the currently executing JAR file" on StackOverflow. Keep in mind it can easily be circumvented (the goal is to discourage tampering, you can't prevent it).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is *no* way to guarantee that the client in use is the client you want them to be using, there are *always* ways around every technique, *even* with a closed source application. When it comes down to it, with a closed-source application, any good reverse engineer with some free time can spoof packets to/from your server. In an open-source application, it would be even easier to have some fun. All you can do is make sure to give the client limited control over the game. The less control you give the client, the less you have to worry about *what* is sending your server packets.

Comment: + and the less the client control over the game, the more client side work in needed.

Comment: Just to expand, be sure that the game server and match making makes it easy for players to avoid cheaters.  Cheating is unavoidable, and the best you can do give players the tools to make their play experience better.  Reputation systems, preferred/avoided player settings, friend lists, and skill-based match making all helps tremendously with this (if implemented well, at least).  It's all about helping players find the kind of people they want to play with.

Comment: @iamcreasy, did you mean, "the more *server-side* work is needed"?

Comment: @cyclops No. Its like predicting / transitioning between 2 states/positions.

Answer (score 2):

I have 2 rules of networking that I keep in the back of my mind when programming.

1. **Give the client, only what information it needs**. This isn't completely relevant to the question, but still on the same topic. The client doesn't need the position of all the gold in the map, if they are no-where near it
2. **Keep it server side**.